# Simulate DOS/High Workload on IIS

Tags: security, iis, web-server, scom

I want to simulate a DOS attack, or a very high workload on a simple IIS web site. The purpose is testing SCOM responses with IIS.

Any suggestions for a tool and/or script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Jmeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) is great for this. It's not 100% obviously how to use as it's quite flexible, but there are plenty of load-testing tutorials out there for it.

Comment: having some issues here, I added an environmental variable, installed java, but it's throwing a "Files was unexpected at this time", and closes. Win7, tried in XP comp mode, any ideas?

Comment: runs fine on an XP systems. This works great FYI, thanks Mark.

Comment: >throwing a "Files was unexpected at this time"

This is due to the space in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\jMeter\bin\ApacheJMeter.jar` in jmeter.bat. Still trying to figure out how to fix it.

Comment: Gist showing how to make it work: https://gist.github.com/tclancy/cf1a1ed00ebc4b2da613

Answer (score 1):

Paessler makes such a tool and there is a free trial. [Paessler Tool](http://www.paessler.com/webstress)  There are lots more but support from these folks is great